# How to retrieve row number from a filtered list

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to retrieve a row number from a filtered list that has the same value for multiple rows. I am currently using the code below, but I need it to return row 7, but it keeps returning "1". I am not sure how to join these two pieces of logic together. I have a snip-it of my filtered list below.

```
Sub Macon()
P = Application.Match("Train", Range("A:A"), 0)
H = Application.Match("Monday", Range("B:B"), 0)

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Loop the rows and test each pair till you find the match then return the row, you can also test that the row is visible to ensure you get the correct match.

Comment: Are you looking for the last row where both terms match?

Comment: `? Activesheet.Evaluate("=MAX(ROW(B1:B1000)*SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(B$1,ROW(B1:B1000)-1,0))*(B1:B1000=""Train"")*(C1:C1000=""Monday""))")`  Subtotal  103 = "countA only if cell is visible"